# Populating an admin multiselect with channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, control-panel, fields, multiselect

I am trying to work out how to populate an admin multiselect menu from entries within another channel.

Basically I just want to allow my client to be able to add new values to the multi-select without giving them access to all the channel fields.

I thought the 'populate from another channel field' would work but it doesn't seem right.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you see MX Select Plus: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-select